# can features module provide fields to an entity created by a different module?

Tags: 7, features

A contrib module provides an entity and some default fields in its contribmodulename.install file.

In the UI we have added fields to that entity.  It appears like these fields, both $field_bases and $field_instances are exported properly in our custom "features" module.  But reverting the feature on our test/staging site does not add the fields to the entity.

Should it?  Or is that not possible because the entity was created by a different module?

Comment: Have you tried to put the whole entity (entity type?) into the feature?

Comment: The entity is the "recurring entity" provided by commerce_recurring module.  When I do `drush fc` there doesn't appear to be any way of exporting the whole entity or entity type.

Comment: 1. Commerce Recurring 7.x is currently unsupported. 2. Seems you also need https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_features to make Commerce play nicely with Features at all.